# unordered_map emplace with default constructor

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map, emplace

I have unordered_map with key value pairs of type string and aClass respectively; where aClass can not be moved(it has a mutex). I don't want it to be copy-constructed either; I think it wouldn't be wise to copy-construct a class that contains a mutex.
To delay the construction of the item until its insertion to the map, I have tried to insert it to the map using emplace, therefore, the second argument must be empty:

```
aList.emplace("aString");
```

however, the previous line did not work.
Any ideas how to emplace using the default constructor?
I have also tried:

```
aList.emplace("aString", void);
aList.emplace("aString", {});
aList.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,"aString");
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use [`std::unordered_map<>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) that creates new elements using the default constuctor:

```
auto& element = m["aString"]; // Creates a new element or gets an existing one.
```

Or, if the return value is not needed:

```
static_cast<void>(m["aString"]);
```

Comment: Are yours and the following expression the same? (void) (m["aString"])

Comment: @b.g. Yes, `(void)expr;` and `static_cast<void>(expr);` have the same effect.

Comment: m["aString"]; expression sufficed. @Maxim, my compiler gcc that has -Wall and -Wextra flags doesn't warn me for using m["aString"] extression, without casting to void. Should I worry?

Comment: @b.g. That cast to `void` serves 2 purposes: disable the compiler warning, if any, and document that you ignore the return value on purpose rather than by mistake.

Answer (score 9):

If you have access to C++17, you can use [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace):

```
myMap.try_emplace("someKey");
```

This will default-construct a new element with the key "someKey".

Prior to C++17, you can use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) using `std::pair`'s `std::piecewise_construct` constructor and an empty tuple for the value's arguments:

```
myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple("someKey"),
              std::tuple<>{});
```